# The position of the ellipsis generated by text-overflow is not as expected

Tags: html, css

There's a table where an image and a link are placed on each row. I want to make the link placed in the middle of the table cell, and in addition, the link text should be shortened to meet the container size.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div>
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="">
                <a href="">FreeBSD-10.1-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" alt="">
                <a href="">goagent-goagent-db0b5c0.tar.gz</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And the css is as follows:

```
div {
  border-style: solid; 
  border-color: #ff0000;
  width: 200px;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 0;  
}

table td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border-style: solid; 
  border-color: #000000;      
}   

table a { 
  text-decoration:none;
  vertical-align: 50%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

However, the rendering result is not what I expect:

[image: The real result]

My ideal result is like this, say, the ellipsis should be on `the same line` with link text:

[image: My expected result]

So how to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: put the ellipsis on the anchor or vertical align the anchor to the bottom, I think your image is causing the ellipsis to be pushed down as it is larger than the line height of the link

Comment: @Pete Thank you for your reply. Did you mean the ellipsis is not part of the anchor text?

Comment: no, it's part of the td as you have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
table a{ 
  text-decoration:none;
  /*vertical-align: 50%;*/
  margin-left: 10px;
} 

table img{
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mk9n1mcu/

Comment: Wow, thanks! It's what I want. But I still have a question: why does applying `vertical-align: middle` on `image` rather than `anchor` make the great difference? Is the ellipsis not part of the anchor text?